# Does Create Amazon EC2 (AWS) intance take long time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, initialization, instance

I stuck on Initiating Instance Launch (Launch status) page for a long time.
My instance type is m3.xlarge (Amazon EC2).
Is about 10-20 minutes ago. Why?

Comment: Can you provide any code sample of what you are doing?

Comment: sorry, there is no any code. that is amazon ec2 instance issue.

Comment: So, launching from the console? If you log in to the console from another browser window, do you see any signs of your new instance in the list? Anything showing for your region in the status dashboard? http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: I checked all the region. There is no any instance created. I also checked from [status.aws.amazon.com](http://status.aws.amazon.com)  , all the services are operating normally

Answer (score 0):

it does take 10-20 minutes to create an ec2 instance, I noticed during the early mornings like 2 am Friday it creates them way faster.